# tangled syntactic bit in C

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I'm having a hard time trying to understand this bit, which writes a string to a field of a structure:

```
struct_t* P = (struсt_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct_t))
size_t offset = offsetof(struct, field);
char **strfield = (char **)(((char *)P) + offset);//the bit I don't fully understand
gets (string); 
*strfield = malloc (strlen (string) + 1);
strcpy (*strfield, string);
```

How do I entangle it correctly? I mean, the parentheses and asterisks.

P.S. this is a part of a program in which offset value defines behaviour of a function depending on the argument with offset value it was called with. That is, it either fills in P->gender or P->whatever.

Comment: I don't understand the need for `offsetof` here. Line 3 is equivalent to `char **strfield = (char **) &P->field`. If `field` is already of type `char *`, you don't need a cast either.

Comment: This is a part of a program in which offset alters behaviour of a function depending on the argument with offset value it was called with. That is, it either fills in p->gender or p->profession. I simplified it into one block of code so that I wouldn't have to go into unnecessary details.
Eg: `my_function(*P, gender)`
with struct being defined as
`typedef struct people{`
 `char* gender;`
` char* profession;`
`} struct_t`

Comment: This doesn't make **any** sense. You can't pass `gender` to `my_function`, unless `my_function` is not a function or `gender` is not a structure field. I think your simplified code is lacking some necessary details.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I can if I make use of proprocessing macro `#define my_function(struct_name, string, struct_field)`. As for this case, I think I can pass `offsetof` the particular field I want to be changed. However, my next step will be writing a function that would receive not only different fields but also fields of different type, but that will be another story.

Comment: Never use the `gets` function. It is inherently unsafe and has been removed from the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `strfield` to point to `field` in `P`. `field` is a `char *` member in the structure, so its pointer `strfield` is a `char **` variable.

`field` will be at `P` starting address + `offset` bytes.

Due to pointer arithmetics, if you want `offset` bytes to be added you have to cast P to a `char *`, otherwise you'll add `offset` times the size of `struct_t` structure.

Comment: I take it that if I wanted to access `int myint` field I would only have to create a pointer that would look like int `*intfield`, am I right? Thus having `int *intfield = (int *)(((int *)P) + offset)`

Comment: @Dan No, it'd be `(int *)((char *)P + offset)` because offset is in bytes. What you wrote is equivalent to `(int *)P + offset`, and it'd move `offset` ints forward, which is not what you want.

Comment: It's as @user4815162342 says. The inner cast is always to `char *` because you want to move `offset` bytes.

Comment: Thanks! If I understood the reasoning correctly, this is because size of int is only 2-4 bits while we need to move by bytes, so using (int*) would not reach the field we were after, right? And if the size of `int` were 8 bits it would be correct to use it instead of `char`?

Comment: @Dan That is. The inner `char *` is not related to the field type. In your example it's just a coincidence.

Comment: @Dan Size of `int` is much greater than 2-4 *bits*. The standard allows a variety of sizes, and typical modern C implementations have 4 **byte** (32-bit) ints. In C, the pointer arithmetic on `T *p` such as `p += 1` moves the pointer by `sizeof(T)` bytes, not by a single byte. The inner cast to `char *` ensures that the arithmetic is performed on the only type with the guarantee that `sizeof(T) == 1`, the `char` type.

Comment: I see. So basically casting `int*` instead of `char*` would move the pointer by `sizeof(int) times offset`, that is 4 times further than with `(char*)` ,correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: After this answer was written, the question has been clarified somewhat which might make the answer less suitable. However, I'm leaving the rest of it unchanged because it still remains unclear what the OP's *actual* code looks like.

It looks like whoever wrote this code needed to store different types in the same field of the struct. Why else would you jump through such hoops just to access a structure member? It would be illuminating to see the definition of `struct_t`, but let's say it looks something like this:

#### The bad way

```
struct struct_t {
  T1  f1;
  T2  f2;
  int field;
};
```

In order to use the `field` member for different types of data at different times, you need to access it through a pointer of the appropriate type.

First we need the address of the `field` member:

```
size_t offset = offsetof(struct, field);
```

The `offsetof` operator gives you the offset of a struct member, from the first byte of the struct. You then need to compute a pointer to this address, and cast it to the appropriate type.

You start with a pointer to the first byte of the struct, and cast it to a character type:

```
char **strfield = (char **)(((char *)P) + offset);
```

Then you add the offset:

```
char **strfield = (char **)(((char *)P) + offset);
```

If you want to store a pointer to char (`char *`) in `field`, then the **pointer to** `field` must be a **pointer to** pointer to char (`char **`):

```
char **strfield = (char **)(((char *)P) + offset);
```

Now we want to store something in `field`, but using `strfield` to store the actual type of data that we want:

```
*strfield = malloc (strlen (string) + 1);
strcpy (*strfield, string);
```

`*strfield` dereferences our pointer to `field` and the pointer returned from `malloc()` is stored at the location of the `field` member inside the struct, and a string is copied to the allocated memory.

#### Why is this bad

It is bad because the `field` member is not necessarily properly aligned for the types you want to store. This causes **undefined behaviour** which could result in the program crashing, running slowly, giving incorrect results or something completely unexpected. Or worst of all, running perfectly for years **until** you make a demonstration for a big customer.

Fortunately, C has the means to do this properly:

#### The good way

The proper, and much easier, way is to use a `union`:

```
struct struct_t {
  T1 f1;
  T2 f2;
  union {
    int intfield;
    char *strfield;
    int (*functionfield)(char *, ...);
  } field;
};
```

Now, you can access the `field` member as `P->field.strfield` or any of the other types and be guaranteed that the field is properly aligned for all of the types inside the union.

Of course, the behaviour is only defined if you store and retrieve a value through the same union member, or at least through a pointer of the **same type**.

Comment: `typedef struct people { char* gender, int age, char * education} struct_t`
Actually, the idea didn't have anything to do with passing _different_ types of arguments. It was only meant to fill in different fields of type `char*`, say, `struct->gender` and `struct->education` with one function, not using `if` `else if` conditions to check if the function has to fill in one field or another.
However, thanks for a good clarification, it was interesting to learn about the trick with unions as fields.

Comment: _It is bad because the field member is not necessarily properly aligned for the types you want to store._

Why is it?

Comment: @Dan: Now that I know the struct definition, the alignment is not a problem. It's just a horribly convoluted way of saying `&P->education`, or in a macro `#define FP(P,F) &(P)->(F)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 
_the alignment is not a problem._ In which type of structure that would be a problem? My guess is that you were referring to structures with structures/unions as fields, am I right? And because of those padding bytes `offsetof` wouldn't work properly, right?

Comment: @Dan: Alignment is a problem when you access an object through an incorrectly typed pointer. Accessing structure or union members through the actual member names will always work.

Comment: Downvoted because the explanation is not correct. If you use offsetof to get the offset of a field it always give you the right address no matter how data is aligned. If instead of using offsetof you use sizeof previous fields to get the pointer you'd be right, and you could get wrong values depending on how data is aligned.

Comment: @NisseEngström Anyway, I'll be looking at this question. If it is fixed (or if you fix my own comment :D) I'll change my vote.

Comment: @sharcashmo: My answer was based on the assumption that there was some kind of type-punning going on. That turned out to not be the case. I'll probably delete my answer to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Ok @NisseEngström. Fixing it is OK for me, also. It is a nice addition to possible methods to access fields in a struct, the only problem for me was that AFAIK it is not correct about the problem with data alignment when using offsetof.

Comment: @sharcashmo: If you have a field of type `T1` and access it using a pointer to an incompatible type `T2`, then the alignment might not be correct. I'll see if I can reword my answer.

Comment: @sharcashmo: My answer is not wrong, when the assumption is that there is some kind of type-punning going on. It is hard to tell, because the code posted by the OP is obviously substantially different from the _actual_ code.

Comment: @NisseEngström I know that. I thought you were telling that the field was not correctly addressed (the actual question leaded me to that mistake) depending on how bytes were packed. Anyway, I cannot remove the downvote while you don't edit the question :/

Answer (score 1):

```
char **strfield = (char **)(((char *)P) + offset);//the bit I don't fully understand
```

Is another way of generically accessing a field within a struct. The `strfield`, presumable sting-field, is a pointer to a pointer which will be used to hold the address of a pointer to the string field within a struct. When you have a struct, you can access its members with either the normal `.` or `->` operators **or** with the name of the struct `+ offset`.

What the code above does is create a pointer to a pointer at address `P + offset` in order to access the member of the struct at that address. For example if you had a struct:

```
struct mystruct {
    int myint;
    char *mystr;
} mystruct;
```

And you wished to access `mystruct.mystr`, you could create a pointer to `mystruct + offset` where offset is equal to `sizeof (int)`. So you would create a pointer (or pointer to pointer) holding the address `mystruct + sizeof (int)` in order to access `mystr` at that address. This manner of access is often used in generic data structures (linked lists, etc.) making use of void data types and the like. Hope this helps.

An additional tool, the `offsetof` command can help in the offset calculation. For a more in-depth explanation and good example, see `man offsetof`

Comment: IMHO, it is better using offsetof than adding the size of the previous fields, because the latter can yield wrong addresses depending on how structures are packed.

Comment: Agreed. I probably should have emphasized that rather than focusing on dissection of the code provided. Good catch.